# Allowing user to save contents of html list to text file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net, text-files

I'm working on an application (ASP.NET, Webforms) that generates a list of outputs based on a user input. I want to allow the user to save the contents of said list as text file, or possibly as other filetypes such as .csv. What is the best way to approach this? Can it be done client-side with Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to use `ActiveX` or `Java Applets` or `Silverlight` to do something like that. JavaScript does not have access to local file system.

Another way to go with this is create a file on server (physically or on the fly) and make it available for download to the user. That will get him the save file dialog.

To do this on the fly, create a blank page (without any markup. not even ), set `Response.ContentType = 'text/plain'` and use `Response.Write()` to write your content in `Page_Load`.

Comment: Is there a way to do it serverside and then pass the resulting file to the client?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a plain text or csv file purely in client-side JavaScript by constructing and opening a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#JavaScript).

Example using jQuery:

```
window.open(
    'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + 
    escape(
        $('#yourlist li') // <- selector for source data here
            .map(function(){
                // format row here
                return $(this).text();
            })
            .get()
            .join('\r\n')
    )
);
```

Unfortunately, this technique will not work in IE due to lack of data URI support until IE8 and security restrictions once [IE added support for data URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28VS.85%29.aspx).  You'd have to use an alternative technique for IE, either hitting the server again or using ActiveX / Silverlight / Flash / Java Applet to avoid a round trip for data that is presumably already on the client.

Comment: Here's are my modifications to your code: http://jsfiddle.net/radu/Y2e93/. Question though, how can I make it so that the user is actually prompted to save the file to disk?

Comment: It's mostly a matter of the media type specified at the start of the URI.  If the browser thinks it can handle the media type `text/plain` it will display it but with a media type such as `text/csv` the browser will hand it off.  `application/octet-stream` forces the download in Firefox but isn't working for me at all in Chrome.

For precise control over the browsers behavior you really need to use HTTP headers especially Content-Disposition.  See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheContentDispositionSagaControllingTheSuggestedFileNameInTheBrowsersSaveAsDialog.aspx